# I cannot seem to find 'add comment' anywhere when looking at other people's questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Bit of an odd question but I cannot seem to find 'add comment' anywhere when looking at other people's questions.

Do I have to have a certain reputation first or am I being blind?

Please can you also add this to the correct place - not sure where to put this question.

Comment: I can see add comment for my own question though?!

Comment: Thanks, early days as I am on 16 but I will get there one day.

Comment: First, stop calling Stack Exchange a Forum...just don't do that. Second...ahm...yeah, welcome to Meta!